# Excel - If confition then sum dynamic range/label

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum, label

Excel Content

```
     A      B       C         D     
01    Label Value   Result  Expect result
02    Car       2       4       10
03    Car       2       4       10
04    Car       2       4       10
05    Car       2       4       10
06    Car       2       2       10
07    Van       1       2       5
08    Van       1       2       5
09    Van       1       2       5
10    Van       1       2       5
11    Van       1       1       5
12    Boat      3       6       15
13    Boat      3       6       15
14    Boat      3       6       15
15    Boat      3       6       15
16    Boat      3       3       15
```

> i try to use if condition and sum but not work...
>   e.g for C1 `=if(A2=A3,sum(B2:B3),B2)`
>   e.g for C2`=if(A3=A4,sum(B3:B4),B3)`

1. I have been sorted the data by label
2. How can i count the total of value if next label is not equal ?

Comment: Take a look at `SUMIF` formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in Cell D2, then copy it and paste all the way down to the bottom of column D:

```
            =SUMIF(A$2:A$16, "="&A2, B$2:B$16)
```

Answer (score 0):

in cell c2 put the following:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$16,--($A$2:$A$16=A3))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more conventional layout for the results would be to insert rows below each group of `Labels`s such as with Subtotal. However Group totals could be added row by row to the standard Subtotal functionality with:

```
 =VLOOKUP("* Total",A2:B16,2,0)
```

in C2 and copied down to suit.